# Plotting Relative angular velocity of a Universal joint

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot the output angular velocity of a [Universal Joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_joint) relative to it's input angel which I call phi (in the link above phi= landa_1).
I'm using MATLAB to do this

> please note the translations of the notation in the link and my code that is:
>
> beta=Beta, phi=landa_1, Omega_2=Omega_B, Omega_1=Omega_A

here is my code:

```
  clear all, close all, clc
  phi=0:360; % one rotation of the input shaft
  Beta=60;
  Omega_A=1;
  Omega_B=(Omega_A*cos(Beta))./(1-((sin(Beta))^2)*((cos(phi)).^2))
  plot(phi,Omega_B,'LineWidth',2), grid on
```

BUT! the plot is not what [it should look like](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/UJoint1.png) (which is available in the link above)
[My current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNhNv.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert degree to radian in order to use `sin` and `cos`. So

```
clear all, close all, clc
phi=0:360; % one rotation of the input shaft
Beta=60;
Omega_A=1;
Omega_B=(Omega_A*cos(Beta/180*pi))./(1-((sin(Beta/180*pi))^2)*((cos(phi/180*pi)).^2))
plot(phi,Omega_B,'LineWidth',2), grid on
```

Output:
[image]